# react grid layout not getting changed on data change reactively

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-grid-layout

I have two routes /abc and /xyz.
When changing route from one to another the grid layout remains the same, it properties does not change but on hard reload they get changed and gives expected result. 
There are following two classes:

Class 1:

```
export default class ConfigureWelcomeScreenGridLayout extends Component{
         constructor(props){

 super(props);
    this.onLayoutChange=this.onLayoutChange.bind(this);
    this.rendergrids=this.rendergrids.bind(this);
    this.saveLayout=this.saveLayout.bind(this);
    let layout=[{"i":"text",x:0,y:0,w:2,h:4},{"i":"image",x:4,y:5,w:2,h:4},{"i":"vedio",x:6,y:8,w:2,h:4}];
    this.state={
        layout:null,
        render:false
    }
}
onLayoutChange(layout,allLayouts){
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(allLayouts));
    console.log(this.state.layout);
    this.setState({
        layout:layout
    });
    console.log(this.state.layout);


}

saveLayout(){
    let layout=[];
    _.map(this.state.layout,function(item){
        let grid={};
        grid.x=item.x;
        grid.y=item.y;
        grid.h=item.h;
        grid.w=item.w;
        grid.i=item.i;
        // console.log(grid);
        layout.push(grid);
    })
    console.log(layout);
    Meteor.call('saveGridLayout',layout,localStorage.getItem('token'),function(err,res){
        if(res.status=="ok"){
            FlowRouter.go("/");
        }
    })
}

rendergrids(el){
        var removeStyle = {
          position: 'absolute',
          right: '2px',
          top: 0,
          cursor: 'pointer'
        };
        var i = el.add ? '+' : el.i;
        if(el.i=="text"){
            return (
              <div key={el.i} className="grid-view" data-grid={el}>
                {el.add ?
                  <span className="add text"  title="You can add an item by clicking here, too.">Add +</span>
                : <span className="text"><div className="grid-text break-word" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.configureDashboard ? this.props.configureDashboard.dashBoardText:""}}></div></span>}
                <span className="remove" style={removeStyle} >x</span>
              </div>
            );
        }
        if(el.i=="vedio"){
            return (
              <div key={el.i} className="grid-view" data-grid={el}>
                {el.add ?
                  <span className="add text"  title="You can add an item by clicking here, too.">Add +</span>
                : <span className="text">
                    <video autoPlay className="grid-video"  controls>
                        <source  src={this.props.configureDashboard ? this.props.configureDashboard.vedioUrl:""} type="video/mp4" />
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                </span>}
                <span className="remove" style={removeStyle} >x</span>
              </div>
            );
        }
        if(el.i=="image"){
            return (
              <div key={i} className="grid-view" data-grid={el}>
                {el.add ?
                  <span className="add text"  title="You can add an item by clicking here, too.">Add +</span>
                : <span className="text"><img className="grid-image" src={this.props.configureDashboard ? this.props.configureDashboard.imageUrl:""} /></span>}
                <span className="remove" style={removeStyle} >x</span>
              </div>
            );  
        }
}

render(){
    if(this.props.configureIsReady && this.props.layoutIsReady ){
        let layout=[ { x: 8, y: 0, h: 2, w: 3, i: 'text' },   { x: 5, y: 0, h: 2, w: 3, i: 'image' },  { x: 0, y: 0, h: 2, w: 5, i: 'vedio' } ];
        return (
            <div className="containar col-lg-12">
              <ReactGridLayout  onBreakpointChange={this.onBreakpointChange} onLayoutChange={this.onLayoutChange}   width={1200}
                breakpoints={{lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768, xs: 480, xxs: 0}}
                cols={{lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2}} rowHeight={30} >


                    {this.props.layout ? _.map(this.props.layout.layout,this.rendergrids) : _.map(layout,this.rendergrids)}
              </ReactGridLayout>
              <button onClick={this.saveLayout}>Save Layout</button>
          </div>
        )
    }else{
        return(
            <Loader options={options}loaded={false} className="spinner">

                </Loader>
        )
    }
}
}

export default createContainer(() => {
var handle1=Meteor.subscribe('configureDashboard',localStorage.getItem('token'));
let handle=Meteor.subscribe('gridLayout',localStorage.getItem('token'));
return {
configureDashboard: ConfigureDesktop.findOne(),
configureIsReady:handle1.ready(),
layout:GridLayout.findOne(),
layoutIsReady:handle.ready()
};
}, ConfigureWelcomeScreenGridLayout)
```

Class 2:

```
export default class VenderDashbord extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onLayoutChange=this.onLayoutChange.bind(this);
    this.rendergrids=this.rendergrids.bind(this);

    let layout=[{"i":"text",x:6,y:0,w:2,h:4},{"i":"image",x:4,y:5,w:2,h:4},{"i":"vedio",x:0,y:8,w:2,h:4}];
    this.state={
        layout:null,
        render:false
    }
}
onLayoutChange(layout,allLayouts){
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(allLayouts));
    console.log(layout);
    this.setState({
        layout:layout
    });
    // console.log(this.state.layout);

}

componentDidMount(){
    // console.log("inside the mount");
    // let that=this;
    // setTimeout(function(){
    //  if(that.props.layoutIsReady){
    //      console.log("hello inside the props ready");
    //      that.setState({
    //          layout:that.props.layoutVendor.layout,
    //          render:true
    //      })
    //  }
    // },1000)
}

rendergrids(el){
        var removeStyle = {
          position: 'absolute',
          right: '2px',
          top: 0,
          cursor: 'pointer'
        };
        var i = el.add ? '+' : el.i;
        el.isDraggable=false;
        el.isResizable=false;
        if(el.i=="text"){
            return (
              <div key={el.i}  data-grid={el}>
                {el.add ?
                  <span className="add text"  title="You can add an item by clicking here, too.">Add +</span>
                : <span className="text"><div className="grid-text break-word" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.configureDashboard ? this.props.configureDashboard.dashBoardText:""}}></div></span>}

              </div>
            );
        }
        if(el.i=="vedio"){
            return (
              <div key={el.i}  data-grid={el}>
                {el.add ?
                  <span className="add text"  title="You can add an item by clicking here, too.">Add +</span>
                : <span className="text">
                    <video autoPlay className="grid-video"  controls>
                        <source  src={this.props.configureDashboard ? this.props.configureDashboard.vedioUrl:""} type="video/mp4" />
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                </span>}

              </div>
            );
        }
        if(el.i=="image"){
            return (
              <div key={i}  data-grid={el}>
                {el.add ?
                  <span className="add text"  title="You can add an item by clicking here, too.">Add +</span>
                : <span className="text"><img className="grid-image" src={this.props.configureDashboard ? this.props.configureDashboard.imageUrl:""} /></span>}

              </div>
            );  
        }
}



render(){
    if(this.props.configureIsReady && this.props.layoutIsReady ){
        let layout=[];
        return (
            <div className="containar col-lg-12">

              <ReactGridLayoutDashboard onBreakpointChange={this.onBreakpointChange} onLayoutChange={this.onLayoutChange}   width={1200}
                breakpoints={{lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768, xs: 480, xxs: 0}}
                cols={{lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2}} rowHeight={30}>


                    {this.props.layoutVendor ? _.map(this.props.layoutVendor.layout,this.rendergrids) : _.map(layout,this.rendergrids)}
              </ReactGridLayoutDashboard>

          </div>
        )
    }else{
        return(
            <Loader options={options}loaded={false} className="spinner">

                </Loader>
        )
    }
}
};

export default createContainer(() => {
var handle1=Meteor.subscribe('configureDashboard',localStorage.getItem('token'));
let handle=Meteor.subscribe('gridLayout',localStorage.getItem('token'));
return {
configureDashboard: ConfigureDesktop.findOne(),
configureIsReady:handle1.ready(),
layoutVendor:GridLayout.findOne(),
layoutIsReady:handle.ready()
};
}, VenderDashbord)
```

The Layout does not change/reactively when the position and size changes reactively.
The Old Layout layout persists on route change.
Thanks in Advance.